# Why count callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am working on problem 10: ASYNC JUGGLING in the [learnyounode](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode) tutorials.

> This problem is the same as the previous problem (HTTP COLLECT) in
>   that you need to use http.get(). However, this time you will be
>   provided with three URLs as the first three command-line arguments.
>
> You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the
>   URLs and print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print out
>   the length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch is
>   that you must print them out in the same order as the URLs are
>   provided to you as command-line arguments.

The official solution involves counting callbacks:

```
var http = require('http')
var bl = require('bl')
var results = []
var count = 0

function printResults () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    console.log(results[i])
}

function httpGet (index) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
      if (err)
        return console.error(err)

      results[index] = data.toString()
      count++

      if (count == 3) // yay! we are the last one!
        printResults()
    }))
  })
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
httpGet(i)
```

The program must wait until all three responses have been received before printing them out, so they come out in the same order they were entered.

My attempt involved using a callback to ensure the correct order:

```
var http = require('http')
var bl = require('bl')
var results = []

function printResults () {
  console.log(results[0])
  console.log(results[1])
  console.log(results[2])
}

function httpGet (i) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + i], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
      if (err)
        return console.error(err)
      results[index] = data.toString()
    }))
  })
}

function httpGetAll (callback) {
  httpGet(0)
  httpGet(1)
  httpGet(2)
  callback()
}

httpGetAll(printResults)
```

But this spits out `undefined` three times.  So it seems as though the `printResults()` is being called before the three `httpGet()` lines are executed.  Seems like I don't understand callbacks as well as I thought.

So my question is, is there any way to achieve this using a callback on `httpGetAll()`?  Or do I *have* to count callbacks to `httpGet()`?

Comment: You have to count, or else use Promises. The `http.get()` calls are **asynchronous**. They return immediately, long before the HTTP requests actually complete. The callbacks passed in to `http.get()` are then invoked with the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this spits out undefined three times. So it seems as though the printResults() is being called before the three httpGet() lines are executed. Seems like I don't understand callbacks as well as I thought.

Yes, you are misunderstanding how asynchronous code behaves. The three `httpGet()` ARE executed first but their asynchronous callbacks that have the results are NOT executed until a later event loop tick. If you look in `httpGet`, the code indented 1 level runs on the first tick, which is just really that first line, all the code in the nested callback function that is indented 2 levels does NOT execute on the same tick. That code is just scheduled on the event queue for later after the HTTP response arrives, but node doesn't just wait, it keeps going in the interim.

> So my question is, is there any way to achieve this using a callback on httpGetAll()? Or do I have to count callbacks to httpGet()?

Yes, there are ways to implement this correctly without specifically counting callbacks, however, you must "keep track" of the pending calls somehow. Counting is a straightforward and efficient way to do this, but you could also use an array as a queue of pending calls, remove an element from the queue when each response arrives, and know you are done when the queue is empty. You could also track state in an object per request with a `done` property that starts `false` and you set to `true` when the response arrives, and you check if they are all done by ensuring all `done` properties are `true`. It's not technically counting, but it is book-keeping of a similar nature.